# Python capture group from string, with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python, coming from a basic knowledge of perl.
I'm trying to capture a substring with regex.

```
>>> a='Question 73 of 2943'
>>> import re
>>> re.match("Question.*(\d+)\s+of", a).group(0)
'Question 73 of'
>>> re.match("Question.*(\d+)\s+of", a).group(1)
'3'
```

What I wanted to do was to catch 73 in the group. I assumed that the parenthesis would do that.

Comment: Operator `*` is _greedy_. Use `*?` instead. Or, better yet, insert a `\s` in the regex before the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy. What this means is it will continue to match any character (except for line terminators) 0 or more times. That means the `(\d+)` capture group you have set up will never happen. What you can do is make the `.*` part lazy by adding a `?` so your regex would look like...

```
re.match(r"Question.*?(\d+)\s+of", a)
```

The difference between lazy and greedy regex is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to capture `73` only, you can do 
`re.search(r'\d+', a).group()` which stops searching for a match after finding the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Your .* part will capture any character included a digit. Better to use `except`.

```
Question[^\d]*(\d+)\s+of
```

that should give you `73`